# Google Oauth implementation on application login every time asking for permission to “Have offline access”, why?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My application is prompting each time for having offline access. Could you please help me how to configure this.
Lets say i have implemented for an application login. in that case asking for offline access each time.

It should ask only for the first time, Next time onwards it should just login.
Please let me know if i have to do some configuration for this.

Am using `google-api-java-client Library. 1.17.0 version`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your login url, but I assume, that you are either still using the offline scope or approval_promt=force. Remove them both from your url, if you don't want the user getting prompted.

The problem: you don't know, if you already got a refresh token, so what you're going to want to do is, that you first log the user in, then check, if you need a refresh token and then redirect the user again to google with the right scope.

Comment: Hello, I have removed the offline scope or approval_prompt = force. now Its working fine. But If i clear the browser cookies its again asking for Offline access. Could you please tell me does this stores the info in cookies? My login url is - http://localhost:8080/login.do.. and the url which am forming during the google login is -

Comment: Little code snippet of mine:- String CALLBACK_URI = "http://localhost:8080/pui/index.jsp";
public SaaSOAuthAction()
 { SCOPE = new ArrayList<String>();
SCOPE.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
SCOPE.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPE).build();
 }
 public String buildGoogleUrl() throws IOException
 {
final GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl();
String resurl = url.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).build();
return url;}

Comment: Try revoking the permission for your app from your account: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: Btw: everybody can see your email adress in consent screen (the little triangle right of your application name), maybe delete that comment.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried revoking the access but still not working. This issue is not specific to one mail Id its same case with all my gmail Ids.